# Why is child view controller occupies the entire screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, containers, childviewcontroller

I'm trying to learn how to make child view controller and face the problem: child view controller I made for some unknown reasuns occupies the whole screen instead of view to which I add it. 
Here is my super-simple code:

```
CVCChildViewController *childViewController =
    [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kVCIdentifier];
[self addChildViewController:childViewController];
[self.childView addSubview:childViewController.view];
[childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

And here is storyboard screen: [image]

White UIView (childView) is subview of self.view. And I wand child view controller does not cross this childView bounds. How could I do this?

Comment: You should use container view instead of uiview.

Comment: Does it exist only in IB?

Comment: No you can create/access it programatically as well.

Comment: Read about container view. It's the same UIView as I used in this question. So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Set the constraints properly. Your code will work

Comment: And for childViewController uncheck `resize view from nib` in the storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here was my problem. "Resize View From NIB" should be **unchecked** for child view controller. After that it will be with correct frame. 
That's because this option make viewController.view.frame equal to applicationFrame by default.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `childViewController.view.bounds = self.childView.bounds` before you add as a subview.
Basically you need to set the frame of your childViewControllers view before adding it as a subview , else it would take its default height. 
I hope this helps. 
Cheers

Comment: I should use didMoveToParentViewController right after addChildViewController. That was the first mistake. And the second - you right, I should set frame for child view controller. But I still don't understand why child view controller ignored it's height from IB.

Answer (score 0):

Why you doing that programmatically? In storyboard add `Container View` (instead `View`) and attach your `CVCChildViewController` to it. This should do the trick.

To access sub controller just provide respective `IBOutlet`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works fine in IB, but I want to learn how to do it programmatically - just for fun.